# Python: Let use re-enter input if not string and convert user input to lower case

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python, I have a dataset I'm working with, a column consist of strings like (Blue, Red, Gold, White). I want the user to enter any of these values but I want to make the user input to be case insensitive and reject integer input, that is, if user input "bLue"/"blUe", it should accept the input and if the user enters "7"/"-4"/"0" it should prompt user to re-enter a string value.

```
def user():
    while True:
        try:
            print(f"Blue, Red, Gold, White, Black, Brown")
            user = input("Enter a color: ")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return user
```

When a user enters a number like 3,2,-1,0 it just returns the number, I want it to reject the user input and tell the user to input a string instead , I also want the string input to be non-case sensitive. Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Apologies, I've made an edit; When a user enters a number like 3,2,-1,0 it just returns the number, I want it to reject the user input and tell the user to input a string instead , I also want the string input to be non-case sensitive. Thanks

Comment: Lower-case the input, test whether it's within a set of allowed values. Don't special-case "numbers" here; you just want to reject *any value not within a pre-approved list.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 def user():
    while True:
        colors = ["blue", "red", "gold", "white", "black", "brown"]
        print(", ".join(colors))
        user_input = input("Enter a color: ").lower()
        if user_input in colors:
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
    return user_input
```

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. This should work for what you have described. Let me know if anything else needs to be changed.

Comment: Please I have one more question; What if I'm fetching the color list from a column named "colors" in a dataset, how do i convert that column to all lower case for comparison with user input

Comment: @highclef well if we are talking about a list, say `["Blue", "Green", "Yellow"]`, you can use a list comprehension like `[color.lower() for color in colors]` which will yield a list of colors all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it works for your solution,

```
import re
def user():
    while True:
        print(f"Blue, Red, Gold, White, Black, Brown")
        user = input("Enter a color: ").lower()
        if len(re.findall('.?-?[0-9]+', user)) > 0:
            print("Please enter a valid input, don't pass an number value")
            continue
        if user not in ['blue', 'red', 'gold', 'white', 'black', 'brown']:
            print('Please only enter')
            continue
        else:
            break
    return user
user()
```

Comment: try to run this code, it will true if a string contains a digit

Comment: @user56700 Wrong; `str.isdigit` specifically tests whether a string contains only digits: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: I don't think we need to to validate digit, we can just check if the value is in our lst else ask user for another input

Comment: Yes you can do this but I only did it for different print cases isdigit check for validation, and other one check if its not in the choices,

Comment: @user56700 Nonsense. `isdigit()` is a string method and will return `True` if the string consists only of digits. But it is not a full solution to OP's requirement either because it will return `False` for `"-4"`.

Comment: @user56700 Because a comma isn't a digit.

Comment: @user56700 It returns false for *that particular input*, yes. Doesn't mean it'll *always* do that for any and all inputs.

Comment: Its better to give different errors on different cases hope it will check every numeric input but thanks @highclef already got an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do without use of **try except**.

```
def user():
    lis=['blue', 'red', 'gold', 'white', 'black', 'brown']
    while True:
        user_enter=input("Enter the colour: ").lower()
        if user_enter not in lis:
            print("Please provide valid colour input!!")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return user_enter
print("User provided the color: ",user())
```